# Cannot access IIS since port 80 is taken by wampserver

Tags: iis

I am a web developer and use mainly Wampserver as an environment. Wampserver uses port 80. Recently I have a project that uses an application that requires IIS. I enabled IIS, but I cannot access it since -as I assume- port 80 is used by Wampserver.

Is there a way to know which port IIS use, or how to assign a port to it?
I don't want to un-install Wampserver, but have no problem changing its port.

Comment: Change port number on http binding of your website to something other than port 80.

Comment: Are you running the full IIS? Or IIS  Express?  If its the full IIS then you can go to the IIS admin app & bind your site to a different port.